# kbhit test fails to compile 'cannot find -lcurses'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/josh/Projects/Testing grounds/kbhit'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/kbhit
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/home/josh/Projects/Testing grounds/kbhit'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -Iusr/include/ -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/kbhit build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/include/ncurses -L/usr/include/ncurses6 -L/usr/include/ncursesw -lncurses.h 
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses.h
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/kbhit] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/josh/Projects/Testing grounds/kbhit'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/josh/Projects/Testing grounds/kbhit'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 477ms)
```

It appears it cannot find ''lcurses'' but I never defined for it to look for lcurses. I actually added ncurse libraries to be linked.

I have navigated to /usr/include/ncurses and there is in fact the files there should be.

I don't fully know what is going on through this whole compiling stuff it is a little beyond me. I just know that I was told to link the libraries I need. ncurses.h is there this is how I have my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>

using namespace std;


bool kbhit()
{
  int ch = getch();
  if(ch != ERR)
  {
    ungetch(ch);
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}

int main() {

  while(!kbhit())
  {
    cout << "no input";
  }
  cout << "Mummy, it's over.";
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be pleasantly welcome; I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a problem with your c++ code, it's more a problem with your build enviroment, are you using netbeans IDE?

This code as far as I can tell does not require ncruses at all, and the link directive that NetBeans? has set up for you points to a ncruses.h file where it should be something like this "-Wl,-lncurses" or only "-lncurses". So a guess is that somewhere in netbeans where you should point out the library name you have written ncruses.h instead of only ncruses(i think, not sure)

try to ask pkg-config what parameters for ncurses should be on your machine "pkg-config --libs ncurses" and "pkg-config --cflags ncurses"

Comment: I need to do what? Yes I am using netbeans in opensuse because it was the easiest linux distro for me to move into. I don't necessarily know what I am doing beyond navigating. I picked ncurses because I want to be able to compile this for windows too.

Comment: If you look more closely at your error you will see that you are trying to link in a header file instead of a library. somewhere in the project properties you have written ncurses.h instead of ncurses(or ncurses6, that why you should run the "pkg-config --libs" line). I don't use netbeans so I have problem telling you exactly where you should change it

Comment: just looked at your other question regarding ncurses, the same place where you talk about make options should be the part where you today have written "ncurses.h" and it should be only "ncurses"

Comment: "oh i finally got it!!" ; to compile at least. Now it just runs in circles and doesn't recognize any input when there is supposed to be some. now I believe the expression is sol